# Can I create an object from a union of strings type?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
type Color = "red" | "blue" | "green"
```

I want to enable client code like:

```
console.log(Colors.red)
```

Obviously I could create:

```
const Colors = {
  red: "red",
  blue: "blue",
  green: "green"
}
```

But that means whenever a color is added I need to do it in two places, which I want to avoid.  I know that I could exclude the 'Colors' object entirely and just use strings, but I'd like to have it all the same.  Is there a way within typescript to *generate* the `Colors` object from the `Color` type, such that modifying `Color` is all that's required to make a new color available via `Colors.myNewColor` in client code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't compute values from types. However, it can be done the other way around. An [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) is very suitable for your use case. Then you can define a type based on the enum's keys dynamically using `keyof typeof`.

```
enum Color {
  red = "red",
  blue = "blue",
  green = "green"
}

type Colors = keyof typeof Color;
// type Colors = "red" | "blue" | "green"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSs4ATKAXigCJc8SAaLKAIwTGCNPsapoHNdRmSvhQJDAF8MGAC4BPAA5N4SZAGdmAa2CS4AMyhTZW2IhQBuDAHpTOmXMNLe5ElAA%20LBsAfO%203ECSA)